# Emacs theme doesn't works on terminator shell

Tags: shell, emacs, themes, gnome-terminal, terminator

All my Emacs24 themes on gnome-terminal works perfectly. But now I switched to terminator shell and none of the Emacs themes works. The same thing happens with vim and man. What should I set to make it all work?

Comment: you need to set TERM to something like xterm-256color

Comment: yep, I added "custom_command = TERM=xterm-256color zsh" in my terminator's config file. Thx